# Vertical paragraph marker in msword

Tags: microsoft-word

I dont even know what the name of this function would be, but I want to be able to comment a number of paragraphs by having a vertical bar at the right edge of the document like this.

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: You could try using a table with 2 columns, and orient the text vertically in the right column.

Comment: Its a hassle, but you are correct.